# Error Error: Unsupported type: common.api.soap.wsdl.Address used in expression: relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingAddress

Tags: email, email-template, vf-email-template

I am new to the `salesforce` and creating an `VisualForce Email Template` and I have a field which I want to show in VF Email Temlate, but when I am trying to show it

Account object is having the below fields of data type Address (PersonMailingAddress)

[image]

I get the following error, please guide:

> Error: Unsupported type: common.api.soap.wsdl.Address used in expression: relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingAddress

[image]

The Email Template Code that I have written ?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="My Subject Testing" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">   
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >

        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>Full Name</td><td>{!relatedTo.Account.Name}</td><td rowspan="3">Address</td><td rowspan="3">{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingAddress}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>       
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more correct merge would be something more like:

```
{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingStreet}<br />
{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingCity}, {!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingState} {!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingPostalCode}
```

Answer (score 7):

Address is a Compound field which can only be accessible by SOAP or REST API.

You cannot use Address compound field in VFP. You need to use individual fields of the Address.

```
{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingStreet}
{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingCity}
{!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingState}
```

Refer [Address Compound field](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_schema_compound_fields_address.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Mailing Address is a combination of 5 fields (MailingCity, MailingStreet, MailingState, MailingPostalcode & MailingCountry). You cannot add mailing address directly to the Visualforce template. Add Each of the above 5 fields individually to the template.

Comment: How we can get that value? This does not works for me `!relatedTo.Account.PersonMailingAddress.MailingCity`

Comment: It's now seven or nine fields, not five. Longitude and Latitude, plus StateCode and CountryCode if state and country picklists are enabled.

Comment: Oh yes you are tight..

Comment: @user4567570 Two things. You don't need to mention account with relatedto. second mailing city is not sub field of Personalmailingaddress. so try this
!relatedTo.MailingCity